# Use <Space> instead of <RET> in emacs ido mode

Tags: emacs, key-binding

I would like to use the <kbd>space</kbd> key instead of <kbd>Return</kbd> to visit the current file or buffer guessed with `ido mode` in emacs.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: My problem was mostly that the <RET> key is far from home row but C-m is a convenient default alias.
The question is still interesting regarding ido customisation.

Comment: Are you referring to entering data from the mini-buffer?

Comment: @lawlist:  yes, that's what I am referring to.

Comment: Do you think it is possible that the function `ido-complete` (inside the source of `.../lisp/ido.el`) might be responsible for the minibuffer selection?  If so, then perhaps you could experiment with `key-translation-map` and *temporarily* set the `RET` key to `space` within the function (whichever it is) and restore it to its default behavior at the end of the function.  For example, you could copy whatever function is responsible -- paste it into your `.emacs` file and change the name (e.g., `lawlist-ido-complete`) and then use something like `(defalias 'ido-complete 'lawlist-ido-complete`).

Comment: NOTE:  The function at issue may not necessarily be `ido-complete` -- that was just my first guess -- you will need to comb the source of `.../lisp/ido.el` to find the actual function responsible for finishing the minibuffer entry that you are using.  Here is a link that describes how to use the `key-translation-map`:   http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_key-translation-map.html